# Editing an external HTML document with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to edit an HTML document using jQuery, but all solutions I have tried are very restrictive.

I am fetching the document from the server, so I get it as a string. In order to parse the document, I need to add it in the DOM.

When I append it to the body, I lose `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags, which are stripped by the browser (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3218941/654179).

So I tried using an iframe, which is a bit complex: I have to use `contentWindow.document` to fill it manually, then a trick with `contents().find('*').html()` to get the content. Maybe there is a simpler, cleaner way of doing this. But the iframe solution also strips `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags. See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/gNvYn/7/

There is another trick here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751201/654179 but I couldn't use it for writing then reading the document (I need to read it for saving on the server).

So, is there a way to edit (write, then read) an HTML document without losing the structure?

Comment: Do you really have to append it to the DOM? Did you try using just $(varContainingHtmlAsString)?

Comment: Getting the document might actually be less of a problem than writing it. How do you want to do that? Do you have a server side service which accepts text and a file name (for example) and writes the content to that file?

Comment: editing a html document through jQuery is limited and probably not the best solution.  try php

Comment: @bfavaretto: Yes, I tried. See http://jsfiddle.net/anr23/

Comment: @FelixKling: This is a Backbone application and the document is a model. So I can fetch it an the save it to the server. But my problem is the way I edit the content before saving it.

Comment: If browser support is not an issue, you can use the [`DOMParser` with MIME-type `text/html`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9251106/938089?javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties).

Comment: @Rob: this is actually an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the things that you need to change are entirely within the body, then there is a workaround.  Use javascript's indexOf() and slice() methods to split the string into pre-body (which has `<body>` as its last characters), post-body (which has `</body>` as its first characters), and body (everything in the middle).  Then insert the body into the DOM, manipulate it, pull it back out again, use the javascript + operator to stick the three back together again, and send back.  It's a little kludgy, and it's not *exactly* what you asked for, but it should get you where you're going.