# Can I append an HTML document with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery. I know I can use append() to add HTML code within the script, but within the script can I put a link to an HTML document that contains the code? There's a lot of it, so it would get messy in the script.

Comment: Is there some HTML code you are trying to manipulate specifically? if so, do update the question with the same.

Comment: You can use ajax to load the code from an URL and then append it.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2):

You can use '.append()' to add HTML code to any HTML element. if this is what you are asking for.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

You can also download external HTML document and manipulate it's contents.

[Can i manipulate an external HTML document with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751165/can-i-manipulate-an-external-html-document-with-jquery)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is little detail to your question, so anyone’s ability to help is limited.

According to the docs, it can handle  htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/append/
Since it can handle a jQuery, Try making an ajax call and handling the returned chunk of text that way to retrieve the doc (assuming you know how to script a response).
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Although, I would question  why such a large block of text wouldn't just be wrapped in a tag with CSS defining the visibility: hidden with a class toggle()? 
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

If you want the UI to appear dynamic, but you are just fetching a static file, I would use the .toggle() technique, or look into other jqueryUI features to show/hide content.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery provide this function specially for this action. This code create one ajax call and append code in the id specified also you have one callback when finished.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/